# JProgressBar: Why my JProgressBar finished instantly?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

So, let's assume that I have one JProgressBar called `pbProgress`, and a button called `btnFill`.

The code is simple:

```
 private void btnFillActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    int i = 0;

    while(i <= 100){
        pbProgress.setValue(i);
        i++;

        try{
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

With or without the `try catch` it keep finished instantly (well, I'm pretty sure that's not the problem). Can someone solve this? Or am I doing some silly mistake? Thanks for the answers!
Note: this code is actually copied from a youtube video, but in that video the progress bar works properly from 0% to 100% and not instant.

Comment: You need to have it in a different `Thread` or `Runnable`

Comment: Do a Google search for Concurrency in Swing and how to use SwingWorker